# How do I style a specific word with CSS in an HTML element?

Tags: css, fonts, tags

How do I style a specific word within `<p>` tags?
EX: **STUDIO X** is the best studio ever.

^^How do I, using css, make "STUDIO X" a different font than "is the best studio ever?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should do this:

```css
p {
  font-size: 12px;
}

span {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>STUDIO X</span> is the best studio ever
</p>
```

I recommend you to define a specific class for `<p>` and `<span>` tags, it will prevent unexpected overwrites.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you all. It was the `<span>` tag that I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap it with a span tag

```
<p><span class="best_studio">STUDIO X</span> is the best studio ever.</p>
```

and use CSS to define the style

```
.best_studio {
  font-family: Arial,
  font-size: 22px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<span class="nevis">STUDIO X</span>
```

```css
.nevis { font-weight:bold; }
```

Answer (score 1):

other text would loose space if you do it this way

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><strong>STUDIO X</strong> is the best studio ever</p>
```

I believe most browsers' default css will bold a `strong` element, but you can be explicit about it as well and add your own rule

```
p strong { font-weight:bold; }
```

Comment: I'm trying to change it to a different font entirely, not just make it bold. I tried using `<p><span style="nevis">STUDIO X</span> is the best studio ever.` but it didn't work..

Comment: you can add any css rules you want