# How can I conditionally apply styling to one React property in a paragraph?

Tags: css, reactjs, styles

I have such a condition:

```
<p style={{color:props.age >= 10 ? 'green' : 'orange'}}>Age: {props.age}</p>
```

I do not want it to color the **"Age"** only the number.

[image]

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags. See [ask].

Comment: It's really this: [How do I style a specific word with CSS in an HTML element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076085/how-do-i-style-a-specific-word-with-css-in-an-html-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p>Age: <span style={{color:props.age >= 10 ? 'green' : 'orange'}}>{props.age}</span></p>
```